# Dual Monitor on Virtualbox with 3D Acceleration

Tags: virtualbox

I've got Ubuntu running in virtualbox with 3D acceleration enabled. It's working great so far except I can't get it to work with dual monitors unless I disable 3D acceleration (then it becomes too slow to use due to unity).

Any ideas what I could try next?

Answer (score 1):

Virtual Box can provide up to eight **virtual** monitors for a guest operating system. These will be presented in multiple windows on the host. Only in fullscreen mode (or seamless mode if supported by the guest) we can address the physical monitors attached to the host.

> However, in full screen and seamless mode, they will use the available physical monitors attached to the host. As a result, for full screen and seamless modes to work with multiple monitors, you will need at least as many physical monitors as you have virtual monitors configured, or VirtualBox will report an error. You can configure the relationship between guest and host monitors using the view menu by pressing Host key + Home when you are in full screen or seamless mode.<sup>[Virtual Box Manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#settings-display)</sup>

- Fullscreen mode may need the [guest additions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-virtualbox) to be installed in the guest OS.
- Seamless mode is [not working correctly](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch14.html) in the guest OS when running OpenGL with Compiz as the compositing manager.

Comment: I'm still not seeing a way forward. I configured two virtual desktops / spaces and I still get the same issue. I can get to the login screen but then both vbox windows turn black.